# Is my mod-rewrite code correct?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'd like to do the following:

Request:

`http://www.mydomain.com/show/requested/path/here?some=var&some_other=var`

shoud be forwarded to

`index.php?s=show/requested/path/here&some=var&some_other=var`

(the last 3 lines of my code, i think they are correct as far as i know)

if the user tries to send a var with the name "s" via get request he should be forwarded to

`index.php?s=error`

i.e:

- `http://www.mydomain.com/show/requested/path/here?s=var`
- `http://www.mydomain.com/show/requested/path/here?a=b&s=var`
- `http://www.mydomain.com/show/requested/path/here?a=b&s=var&c=d`
- `http://www.mydomain.com/show/requested/path/here?a=b&s`
- `http://www.mydomain.com/show/requested/path/here?s`

My question is: Is the following code really correct?
it seems to match the 5 cases. But I do not know if it matches other cases that it shouldnt. My goal is to not allow to send a var called "s" via get request.

**Content of my .htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)(\?|&)s=?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?s=error [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not correct because your 2nd rule will inject `?s=...` into Request URL and that will match first rule in 2nd pass and will result in `?s=error.

Replace your code with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)s=error(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+.*?[?&]s\b [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?s=error [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)s=[^&]+(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note use of `%{THE_REQUEST}` which represents original request and doesn't change with application of various rewrite rules.

Comment: hmmm i got very strage results with your solution. If I remove the R=301 it seems to work. My .htaccess is not directly in the document_root like I explained but i am some folders below. If I use the 301 it tries to redirect to the absolute path of my vm /var/www/.....

Comment: Oops, I had a typo in my first rule that I have corrected now. Please try again.

Comment: now i am able to overwrite the path with s=someting in get vars.

Comment: Can `s=something` appear any where in QUERY_STRING? My answer assumed it is at first place? Let me correct it anyway.

Comment: ahhh i thougt it was easy but it doesnt seems to be! now i am not redirected to index.php but to /show/requested/path/here?s=error which gives me a 404.

Comment: are you really shure that i got a second pass with my first code. It doesnt seems to. it looks like it works.

Comment: Yes Apache keep applying rules as long as it matches any conditions.

Comment: Made some edits and verified in my testing that this answer works fine now.

Comment: no success for `/p/a/t/h?s` which results in an empty s. And no success for `/p/a/t/h?s=error` which shows a 404. The other cases seem to work. EDIT: `/p/a/t/h?s=` is the same as `/p/a/t/h?s` (s="")

Comment: you should earn an oskar for this. `?s` and `?s=` works now. Still 404 on `s=error` but maybe thats not such a big thing for me. For some reasons i will not be redirected to s=error with my first code when not having s=... in my first request. But I should like you explained, shouldn't I?

Comment: I have this condition in my 1st rule: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)s=error(&|$) [NC]` which basically means don't apply this rule if URI already has `s=error` in Query String. Let me know if you don't want it and want another way to handle this special case.

Comment: ah ok, if i remove the first line it works like i expected. if the user types s=error he should be redirected to index.php?s=error. if he types /error the same should happen. I will accept your answer but i wonder that there is no easier solution. mod_rewrite and regex will kill my brain sometimes.

Comment: mod_rewrite and regex both became a bit complicated after applying all of our requirements and the fact that `s=error` could appear any where in the Query String.